# Type conversion to a structure which has another structure ptr in it

Tags: c, casting, segmentation-fault

My data has structure like the following:

```
typedef struct struct2 {
  uint8_t  num;
  uint8_t  action;
  uint8_t  id;
} struct2_t;

typedef struct struct1 {
  uint8_t  title;
  struct2_t* content;
} struct1_t;
```

I assigned a memory space to a structure pointer and printed out the value.

```
void main(){

    const uint8_t msg[5] = {
            5, 4, 3, 2, 1
    };

    struct1_t *req = NULL;
    req = (struct1_t *)msg;

    printf("%d ", req->title);
    printf("%d ", req->content->num);
    printf("%d ", req->content->action);
    printf("%d ", req->content->id);

}
```

The result is:
5 5 4 3
while I expected it to be 5 4 3 2?

Besides, in another place I copy the content in my buffer and do the similar thing.

```
void main(){

    const uint8_t msg[5] = {
            5, 4, 3, 2, 1
    };

    uint8_t *test = NULL;
    test = (uint8_t*)malloc(5 + 1);
    memset((test), 0x00, 5);
    memcpy(test, msg , 5);

    struct1_t *req = NULL;
    req = (struct1_t *)test;

    printf("%d ", req->title);
    printf("%d ", req->content->num);
    printf("%d ", req->content->action);
    printf("%d \n", req->content->id);
}
```

But this time I can not access the struct2_t pointer

5 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Thanks for you help

Comment: +1 for making the typedef name and struct tag distinct, and for applying the _t convention consistently with the standard library. (But main should return `int`.)

Comment: My guess is that you have not yet discovered the variance in padding that compilers will add to a struct to provide alignment. You will also want to look at `man offsetof` for a means of determining the padding the compiler applies.

Comment: Contrary to the assertion in your tittle, you *do not* declare a structure that contains another structure.  You declare a structure that contains a **pointer** to another structure.  These are not at all the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to be missing is a clear understanding when to use the `dot` (`.`) operator with a structure and when to use the `arrow` (`->`) operator.

The rule is simple. If you have a `struct`, you access its members with the `.` operator. If you have a `pointer to a struct`, you access its members with the `->` arrow operator. When you have a `struct` containing a `pointer to a struct`, then use use *one of each*.

The following example should make that clear as well as providing examples of using your `content` pointer to point to a struct with automatic storage `s2` and a struct stored in dynamically allocated memory 's3'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

enum { MAXL = 128, MAXC = 512 };

typedef struct struct2 {
uint8_t  num;
uint8_t  action;
uint8_t  id;
} struct2_t;

typedef struct struct1 {
uint8_t  title;
struct2_t *content;
} struct1_t;

int main (void) {

    struct2_t s2 = { 5, 4, 3 }, *s3 = NULL;
    struct1_t s1 = { 2, &s2 };  /* content initialized to s2 */

    /* using address of s2 as content */
    printf ("\n title  : %" PRIu8 "\n"
            " num    : %"   PRIu8 "\n"
            " action : %"   PRIu8 "\n"
            " id     : %"   PRIu8 "\n", s1.title, 
            s1.content->num, s1.content->action, 
            s1.content->id);

    /* dynamic allocation of s3 */
    if (!(s3 = calloc (1, sizeof *s3))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    s3->num    = 8;  /* assignment of values to s3 */
    s3->action = 7;
    s3->id     = 6;
    s1.content = s3; /* update content pointer to s3 */

    /* using address of s3 as content */
    printf ("\n title  : %" PRIu8 "\n"
            " num    : %"   PRIu8 "\n"
            " action : %"   PRIu8 "\n"
            " id     : %"   PRIu8 "\n", s1.title, 
            s1.content->num, s1.content->action, 
            s1.content->id);

    free (s3);  /* don't forget to free all memory you allocate */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/structnested

 title  : 2
 num    : 5
 action : 4
 id     : 3

 title  : 2
 num    : 8
 action : 7
 id     : 6
```

Look over the example and let me know if you have any further questions, or if I missed a part of your question, let me know that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clear example. I tried the way to initialize and it works.

Comment: Glad I could help. Let me know if you have any other questions. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `content` so you get undefined behavior. You need to do:

```
/* ... */

    req = (struct1_t *)msg;
    req->content = (struct2_t *)&msg[1];

    printf("%d ", req->title);

/* ... */
```

Typepunning is not recursive.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out type running is not recursive, But base on the above other answers, I might not be able to do (struct2_t *)&msg[1] because of padding in my structure.

Answer (score 0):

There are two faws inyour code, first in your struct1 you are using a pointer to a struct2, but you are filling the memoryof your struct1 instance with the data, so one of your values is considered as a pointer. 
Second, you have to consider the alignment of the data within of a structure. Teh compiler places the data depending on its type and your target architecture and fills the spaces with padding bytes. As a 32 bit architecture usually accesses data better if it is 4-byte aligned, the compiler moves your struct1 (or struct1 pointer, too) to the next 4 byte aligned address. So you have in your code

```
0xYYYYYYYY+00 struct1.title (byte0)
0xYYYYYYYY+01 padding byte0
0xYYYYYYYY+02 padding byte1
0xYYYYYYYY+03 padding byte2
0xYYYYYYYY+04 struct1.struct2*
```

if you correct the pointer issue: then you have

```
0xYYYYYYYY+00 struct1.title (byte0)
0xYYYYYYYY+01 padding byte0
0xYYYYYYYY+02 padding byte1
0xYYYYYYYY+03 padding byte2
0xYYYYYYYY+04 struct1.struct2.num
0xYYYYYYYY+05 struct1.struct2.action ( here is no padding,as the data iself is u8)
0xYYYYYYYY+06 struct1.struct2.id( here is one paddingbyte,as the data iself is u8, but at the end of the structure).
```

In general I would propose not to  initialize the srtuct in that way, as it you have to consider alignment logic of the compiler, which can be a bit tricky.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the padding problem. I also tried pack(1) and the padding problem was resolved.